# How do I calculate the Hausdorff dimension of a self-affine fractal (like the Barnsley Fern)?

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

The fractal I am concerned with has an infinite number of self-affine copies of itself, and all scaled to different dimensions. And all but one of them are rotated too. I know this may sound way more 'general' than it should be, but my fractal is like that. Essentially, is there a generalized method/ technique/ formula to calculate to Hausdorff dimension of a fractal? I have the Minkowski-Bouligand dimension, but need the Hausdorff dimension too (as far as my knowledge goes, they are not always equal. what are the necessary conditions for them to be equal?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no closed form expression for the dimension of the attractor of an IFS at this generality. There is some discussion with references in [this Mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168201/).

Comment: CompassBearer, how did you find the Minkowski-Bouligand dimension of the Barnsley Fern?